# PAYMENT RETURN PAGE WITH IOS 7.1.2

Tags: paypal, payment

I have a problem on iPad with iOs 7.1.2. Within return payment page the post variables sent from PayPal can't read from Safari or Chrome; but with my Windows PC I succeed read the variable.

The script is made with classic ASP VBScript, the `request.form` fields are empty when read from iPad, but not with PC.

I use the IPN method to record the transaction on my DB, but I need the return page to give the user information.

Can you help me?